# How to calculate average time of answer between reciever and sender?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `message_conversation`:

```
id | conversation_id | reciever_id | sender_id | message | created_at
______________________________________________________________________
1   1                   1             2            A         2018-08-01
2   1                   2             1            B         2018-08-02
```

I need to get average time of answer for `sender_id = 2` between conversations messages.

I tried this way:

```
SELECT 
 id, created_at 
FROM 
  message_conversation 
WHERE 
  sender_id = 2 OR receiver_id = 2 
GROUP BY conversation_id, created_at
ORDER BY id LIMIT 2
```

As result I expect `2018-08-02 - 2018-08-01` in days, hours, minutes

Comment: *difference* or *average*?

Comment: The avarage time of answer, so I can get difference if there are only two rows convecration

Comment: You should please show more sample data of your table and the expected result to make clear what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Average can be applied on numeric values, such as time differences. There is no such thing as *average time*. Edit your question and clarify what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`to calculate the difference in seconds and then `SEC_TO_TIME()` to convert the average difference back to time format. This only works in mySQL 8 so I have added a second method afterwards.

- **for MySQL 8.0**

> ```
> create table message_conversation (
>   id int,
>   conversation_id int,
>   receiver_id int,
>   sender_id int,
>   message char(2),
>   created_at date
>   );
> ```

> ```
> insert into message_conversation values
> (1,   1,                   1,             2,            'A',         '2018-08-01'),
> (2,   1,                   2,             1,            'B',         '2018-08-02');
> ```

> ```
> with reply_time as
> (select
>   sender_id,
>   conversation_id,
>   UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at) 
>   - UNIX_TIMESTAMP( lag(created_at) over 
>                       (partition by conversation_id 
>              order by created_at)
>   ) as diff_seconds
>   from message_conversation
> )
> select 
>   SEC_TO_TIME(avg(coalesce(diff_seconds,0))) time_diff
> from reply_time
> where coalesce(diff_seconds,0) > 0
> and sender_id = 1 ;
> ```
>
> ```
> | time_diff     |
> | :------------ |
> | 24:00:00.0000 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5479c8fa42455c4a98b89812b2bfe7b1)*

- **for mySQL 5 and below**

> ```
> set @prev = '3000-01-01 00:00:00';
> set @conv = 0;
> select
>   sec_to_time(avg(seconds_diff)) average_difference
> from
> (select
>   case when conversation_id = @conv then
>      TIMESTAMPDIFF(
>     SECOND,
>     @prev,
>     created_at
>     ) end seconds_diff,
>   @conv := conversation_id,
>   @prev := created_at
> from message_conversation) a
> where coalesce(seconds_diff,0) > 0;
> ```

> | average_difference |
> | :----------------- |
> | 24:00:00.0000      |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=193f752ae63487c2c497c93ca80f0cab)*

- **version for 1 specific `sender_id`**

Comment: For MySQL does it work?

Comment: @Alina - my dbFiddle is mySQL, albeit version 8. It doesn't work in version 5 :-(

Comment: I try to run this on 5 version (:

Comment: I did not get this

Comment: @Alina - please see second method for mySQL 5

Comment: What if I need to quey for specific sender_id - 2?

Comment: see further query at the end of the answer